# Retrieving and Displaying Data Based on UUID Relationship in Vue App

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js, axios, relational-database

I have two different database tables, each with a unique UUID. In my Vue App, I have cards generated from Table A's unique UUIDs. When I click a button on a card, Vue Router takes me to a new page/view related to that card with its own unique UUID. The URL also changes to a URL with a unique UUID, so the user sees content related to the clicked card.

```js
 axios
      .get(
        `${config.activeMod.API_BASE_URL}/api/procesos/${this.$route.params.uuid}`
```

In this new view, I have a title, description, employee name, etc., all of which are taken from the same table, and I have no problem up to this point. However, this new component has a child component where I need to show some steps related to the main component, and that data comes from Table B.

Table B has its own unique UUIDs and a JSON object called **"ppp_table_a_uuid,"** which is equal to the table A's unique UUID. The UUID in Table B is different, but its object is exactly the same as the UUID in Table A, making it the only common thing between the two tables. This establishes the relationship between the data in Table B and Table A.

Now, I need to show data from Table B that has the same UUID in its JSON object "ppp_table_a_uuid," so I can add relevant content/info to my component. I want to achieve this using Axios without making an additional GET request because Vue has no idea what's inside the endpoint without it.

I have two possible approaches:

1. Perform a GET request to "process.steps.UUID" (which returns only one JSON object).
2. Use a different route in my backend service, "process.steps.all," which shows all JSONs regardless of their UUID.

Which approach is easier and more reliable? Should I try to solve this problem in my front-end Vue app, or should I modify the backend service, specifically the controller that fetches the data from SQL, so that it shows "ppp_table_a_uuid" as its UUID? (I'm not sure if this is possible, but since I can make joins in SQL, I think I can also do that in SQL.) If I try to solve this in frontend, how to get data from table_b in this logic?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL for both cases.  We can judge it from MySQL's point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue...

I used the endpoint that gives me all steps regardless of UUID's...
And I just used item.filter filtered all JSON objects according to parameters in the router and get only the matching ones.

Now it works just like how I want.